# Apache Oltu Github integration example with Spring MVC

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, oltu

I'm developing an "Apache Oltu Spring MVC Github" integration example. In this example I will be sending "App ID" and "Secret" to get the "access_token" in order to access the protected resources like "Gist", "user" etc.

So first step is to create / register the "App" using https://github.com/settings/applications/new.
Once you create a App make sure to Note: AppID and Secret, we need these values to be used in Spring code.

To develop this functionality / code - I search a lot and I did not find any ready made code. So I decided to furnish / explain my code below. So one can  find these links useful.

I've taken a reference of following URL's to developed whole code:-

- https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/OAuth+2.0+Client+Quickstart
- http://www.jasha.eu/blogposts/2013/09/retrieve-facebook-profile-data-java-apache-oltu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attached is the screen shot to register the "App" on Github. "MyApp" is the App that I created.

[image]

Use the same code from http://www.jasha.eu/blogposts/2013/09/retrieve-facebook-profile-data-java-apache-oltu.html, just make sure to change the

AUTHORIZATION_URL = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";

ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token"

To get Protected Resource like User Profile use: https://api.github.com/user

The output I get when run the code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The user4798111 has mentioned is correct and just adding some more details. Pre-requisite, you need to register App on Github. Once you registered the App, you will get the `CLIENT_SECRET`,`CLIENT_ID` to be used to get the Protected resources from the github.

If you're using the `OAuthClientRequest` API to to make an initial call, you need to have the following details

```
private static final String AUTHORIZATION_URL = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "8515a1e4XXXXXXX";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "ae3487601d891d257f7193XXXXXXXXX";
    private static final String REDIRECT_URL = "http://localhost:8080/apache-oltu/github/redirect";
    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String authenticate() throws OAuthSystemException {
        OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
                .authorizationLocation(AUTHORIZATION_URL)
                .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
                .setRedirectURI(REDIRECT_URL)
                .setResponseType("code")
                .setScope("user,gist,user:email,user:follow,public_repo,repo,repo_deployment,repo:status,repo:invite")
                .buildQueryMessage();

        System.out.println("REDIRECT TO: "+request.getLocationUri());
        return "redirect:" + request.getLocationUri();
    }
```

The same something simllar you would need to use like below

```
request= new OAuthBearerClientRequest("https://api.github.com/user").
                setAccessToken(oAuthResponse.getAccessToken()).
                buildQueryMessage();
```

The information about the scopes and other details can be found here:

- https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/about-authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/
- https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/about-scopes-for-oauth-apps/

The result which could see is below for reference:

```
{  
   "login":"JavaHelper",
   "id":8208031,
   "avatar_url":"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/8208031?v=4",
   "gravatar_id":"",
   "url":"https://api.github.com/users/JavaHelper",
   "html_url":"https://github.com/JavaHelper",
   "followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/JavaHelper/followers",
   "following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/JavaHelper/following{/other_user}",
   "gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/JavaHelper/gists{/gist_id}",
   "starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/JavaHelper/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
   "subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/JavaHelper/subscriptions",
   "organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/JavaHelper/orgs",
   "repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/JavaHelper/repos",
   "events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/JavaHelper/events{/privacy}",
   "received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/JavaHelper/received_events",
   "type":"User",
   "site_admin":false,
   "name":"JavaProgramer",
   "company":null,
   "blog":"",
   "location":null,
   "email":null,
   "hireable":null,
   "bio":null,
   "public_repos":45,
   "public_gists":0,
   "followers":4,
   "following":60,
   "created_at":"2014-07-19T10:03:42Z",
   "updated_at":"2017-09-09T12:55:57Z",
   "private_gists":0,
   "total_private_repos":0,
   "owned_private_repos":0,
   "disk_usage":142270,
   "collaborators":0,
   "two_factor_authentication":false,
   "plan":{  
      "name":"free",
      "space":976562499,
      "collaborators":0,
      "private_repos":0
   }
}
```